# Index out of range - error in function

Tags: arrays, swift, parameters

I have a function with 2 parameters - arrays of Int called Numbers and Numbers1. I want to multiply each element in Numbers on index "i" with each element in Numbers2 on the same index. Then I want to get a total sum of the results from the multiplying. When I call the function, it displays error - Index out of range. Code bellow:

```
var sum = Int()
var Array = [Int]()
var totalsum = Int()

func prumerdanehopredmetu(Numbers:[Int], Numbers2:[Int]) -> Int {
    for i in Numbers {
        sum = Numbers[i] * Numbers2[i]
        Array.insert(sum, at: 0)
    }
    totalsum = Array.reduce(0,+)

    return totalsum
}

prumerdanehopredmetu(Numbers: [1,2,3], Numbers2: [1,2,3])  //error
```

update:

```
for i in Numbers.indices
```

This worked.

Comment: your spacing is... creative.

Comment: Note that variable and parameter names should be `lowerCamelCase`, as per the Swift API design guidelines. `Array.reduce(0,+)` looks like a weird static call on the `Array` type otherwise.

Comment: You probably meant `for i in 0..<Numbers.count`

Comment: Or `for i in numbers.indices`

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint in the function, single-step, inspect the variables,... In such a short program it would be a matter of minutes to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, "i" is equal to the values in "Numbers", not the indices of "Numbers". Here's an example of how such a "for" loop works in Swift:

```
let myArray = ["John", "Timothy", "James", "Tanmay"]
for i in myArray {
    print(i) // "John", "Timothy" ...
}
```

Whereas, your code expects "i" to be 0, 1, 2 ...

In Swift, you can also have a for loop iterate through the indices and values of an array, by enumerating the array:

```
let myArray = ["John", "Timothy", "James", "Tanmay"]
for (index, value) in myArray.enumerated() {
    print(index) // 0, 1 ...
    print(value) // "John", "Timothy" ...
}
```

Of course, in Swift, you can also loop through ***just*** the indices, by finding the indices of the array:

```
let myArray = ["John", "Timothy", "James", "Tanmay"]
for i in myArray.indices {
    print(i) // 0, 1 ...
}
```

So, in order for your code to work, you must loop through the indices of "Numbers", and not the values:

```
func prumerdanehopredmetu(Numbers:[Int], Numbers2:[Int]) -> Int {
    for i in Numbers.indices {
        sum = Numbers[i] * Numbers2[i]
        Array.insert(sum, at: 0)
    }
    totalsum = Array.reduce(0,+)

    return totalsum
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating the numbers (`[1, 2, 3]`), not their indices (`0, 1, 2`). Try this instead:

```
var sum = Int()
var sums = [Int]()
var totalsum = Int()

func prumerdanehopredmetu(_ numbers: [Int], _ numbers2: [Int]) -> Int {

    for i in numbers.indices {
        sum = numbers[i] * numbers[i]
        sums.append(sum)
    }

    totalsum = Array.reduce(0,+)

    return totalsum
}

prumerdanehopredmetu([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
```

There is a much easier/simpler way though. You can just use `zip`, and `map`

```
let products = zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]).map(*) // results in [1, 4, 9]
let sumOfProducts = products.reduce(0, +) // 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func multiply(array1: [Int], array2: [Int]) -> Int {
    if array1.count != array2.count {
        //error handler
        return 0
    } else {
      var i = 0
      var sum = 0
      while i < array1.count {
          sum = sum + array1[i]*array2[i]
          i = i + 1
      }
      return sum
    }
}
```

you should consider your array have different number of values.